# BoxObj and AxisType.Log in ZedGraph 

Tags: zedgraph

In order to emphasize data, I try to draw a box from top to down of the graphpane. This works well as long I stay with a linear axis.

When I change to a log axis the height of the box will not fit. How do I calculate the right height of such a box for log scales?

Answer (score 0):

Change the coordinate frame for your box object. Use the `XAxisYChartFraction`, and (0,1) as the Y coordinates. This should do the trick.